# Text Interface Design

Tags: c#, text, interface, textbox, console

I am currently working on some pseudo-console-like interface, but I have run into a problem.

Is there any way to count how many lines of text can a multiline textbox display?
Also, how do you count how many characters fit into on-screen line if you use a monospace font?

Comment: height of box, height of font will give you a good start, not sure about the line spacing but im sure thats discoverable

Comment: I kinda knew it already, but there are still some issues.

Comment: Are you planning to handle resizing, font changes, ...?

Comment: Just resizing and maybe font size changing.

Answer (score -1):

Well, eventually I figured out that MeasureString method and arithmetics is optimal Solution for now. Thanks Anyway

```
    SizeF csize = gDisplay.MeasureString("█", Font, new PointF(0, 0),
    StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    ScrSize.Height = (int)(gDisplay.ClipBounds.Height / csize.Height);
    ScrSize.Width = (int)(gDisplay.ClipBounds.Width / csize.Width);
```